# generate image dynamically php with get through src

Tags: php, image, src

I've been struggling to find out how to implement a system where you put a function in your php with some parameters and generates a link wich point to a php page and gives out an image. Looking for 'Generate image dynamically' has not help at all. This is an example of what I mean:

Lets say you generate this src like a link

```
 src="MyImageCreatorPage.php?id=12345&width=100"
```

I have been looking to fpassthru($image); with no luck, so far I've been able to generate one image, but when I try more than one it doesn't show but the first one.

```
$fid = $_GET['fileid'];   
// go to database retrieve the file path 
$filename = $retrieved_file_from_datable[0];
$width = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];
// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width_out;
$new_height = $height_out;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height,   $width,         $height);

// Output
$image = imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);

$fp = fopen($image, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($image));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
echo $width;
```

The above code isn't working at all though

Comment: For a start `filesize` expects a file path, not a boolean from `imagejpeg`. Same with `fopen` which is probably failing, which will fail fpassthru. Even with the fixed, you're outputting twice, once with `imagejpeg` once with fpassthru`.

Comment: I'm confused. You say the code works for one image but at the bottom you say it doesn't work at all. Also why are you doing `echo $width` at the end? That would make your output an invalid image (probably).

Comment: Yes I made it work, but then I moved something and is not working anymore, what I said is I made it work for one image, that was before. In filename I put the file path, that's why I said between coments that I do a request to database to request the file path.

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php (for the 2nd parameter) [...]  *If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly* so this probably means anything after the `imagejpeg` function call is redundant.

Comment: Ok, I get the redundant part, I am still learning. But what the main point is that I am trying to figure it out how to accomplish the task of getting an image with <img src="path.php?id=123&params=some" ...